# oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT

Tags: oauth, google-api, raspberry-pi, google-oauth, google-cloud-vision

I am using Google Cloud Vision API on my Raspberry PI. It works fine when I use it on my home (on which the cloud account was first accessed) network but if I access the API from a different network it raises a token refresh error. I have synchronized the time using NTP but is of no help.

Detailed error:

> oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values and use a clock with skew to account for clock differences between systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe.

This is caused by poor synchronisation of the computer's clock where the code was executed that had a lag of 5 minutes or more.   The error means that the token is not valid and its not valid because the time on the PI is different then the actual time.  I know that you say you are checking NTP but I suggest you check timezone as well.

I know this is a PI so debugging is probably limited but try outputting your id token and decryption its a jwt you should be able to see the iat and exp values.  It might help you figure out what time it thinks it is.

Comment: And just wanted to how to output and decrypt it on PI cause I don't have much knowledge about it...and  thank you for the above response

Comment: Sorry I dont have much experience with PI.  You may want to ask a separate question for that.   The main issue here is the time on the PI is incorrect you need to fix that.