# How to fix oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError in google analytics python api

Tags: python-3.x, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When I call GoogleAnalytics REST_API using python it returns the following error message

> **oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant:**
> **Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a**
> **reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.**

I also ref this link: [oauth2client.client.HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49510330/oauth2client-client-httpaccesstokenrefresherror-invalid-grant-invalid-jwt)

but the problem not solved any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that this type of error can appear in at least a couple of situations, one most likely related to the clock (I suggest to investigate this thoroughly because it is usually the problem) and the other due to a generic message related to credentials (https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2076):

- The time of the machine that runs containers drifts from system time, and doesn't appear to reset itself properly. Stopping and restarting (i.e. Docker for Mac) should be fixed the issue, alternatively try outputting your token information to detect any difference in time between it and that of your machine;
- if you are using a credential file that was deleted on my project, so just create another credential file;